# Using Razor with C#: Trying to understand how to save SQL functions & list functions

Tags: asp.net, razor

Is there any way that I can save/keep the SQL functions that we routinely call within our apps? I have 4 database connections as well as a total of 18 lists that routinely get called for approval/editing/verifying.

Is it somehow possible to store those maybe in a variable somewhere? I've been reading up on Helpers and the App_Code folder but I can't seem to figure out a way to reuse a function across various pages.

Thanks.

I was hoping to do something like:

```
@SQL1 or @SQL1()
```

and

```
@SoftlinesList or @SoftlinesList()
```

Comment: Helpers are for generating HTML without repeating yourself. If you want specific data to be passed into your view, it should be part of your model. Or add it to the ViewBag. (Technically the ViewBag works for this, but is meant for simpler items and not complex lists). If neither method works for you, you can access C# code from the view if you like. Just make a public static method and call it.

Comment: if you are using MVC you can create a BaseController and inside the BaseController have these common methods

Comment: It is not recommended to put elaborate function calls into the Views, but rather have the controller pass the data via the view's model. Otherwise you are adding addition bindings between the view and code (which is a bad thing). If you are using Entity Framework a simple way to add this kind of business logic is to use extension methods on the EF entity model, so you can do things like `var mylist = context.SoftLinesList();`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a BaseController and put your common code there and inherit from that BaseController